# In Python , can else block have further if-elif-else blocks?

Tags: python

Movie Tickets: A movie theater charges different ticket prices depending on a person’s age. If a person is under the age of 3, the ticket is free; if they are between 3 and 12, the ticket is $10; and if they are over age 12, the ticket is $15. Write a loop in which you ask users their age, and then tell them the cost of their movie ticket.

I wanted this program to have quit value. I could have used 0 as my quit value but i wanted to use 'quit'.

```
prompt = "What is your age? "
prompt += "\nEnter 'quit' to close program."

age = 0

while True:


     age = raw_input(prompt)
        if age == 'quit':
            break
        else:
            age = int(age)
            if age < 3:
                print("The movie ticket is FREE for you.")
            elif 3 <= age < 12:
                print("The movie ticket is $10 for you.")
            elif age >= 12:
                print("The movie ticker is $15 for you.")
```

Answer (score 6):

I would like to point out that you don't need the `else` clause. You can include the rest of the conditionals at the prior indentation level because `break` exits the loop rather than continuing on with the rest of the body of the loop.

Rather than

```
    if age == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        age = int(age)
```

Simply:

```
    if age == 'quit':
        break

    age = int(age)
```

If that wasn't clear here is the entire program with that change:

```
prompt = "What is your age? "
prompt += "\nEnter 'quit' to close program."

while True:

    age = raw_input(prompt)
    if age == 'quit':
        break

    age = int(age)
    if age < 3:
        print("The movie ticket is FREE for you.")
    elif 3 <= age < 12:
        print("The movie ticket is $10 for you.")
    elif age >= 12:
        print("The movie ticker is $15 for you.")
```

I also removed the useless assignment: `age = 0` as that value is replace by `age = raw_input(prompt)` before it can ever be read.

Comment: Thanks!  What should i do about the rest of the code if do not use the else block ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can nest if statements if you like, but I always try to find a better way first. In this case, we can use the condition part of the while statement.

```py
age = 0
while age != "quit":
    age = raw_input(prompt)
    age = int(age)
    if age < 3:
        print("The movie ticket is FREE for you.")
    elif 3 <= age < 12:
        print("The movie ticket is $10 for you.")
    elif age >= 12:
        print("The movie ticker is $15 for you.")
```

Now the code will loop for as long as `age` is not equal to `"quit"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try:` to avoid the script crashing by entering othert values than integers.

```
prompt = "What is your age? [quit to Exit the program] : "
while True:
     age = raw_input(prompt)
     if age == 'quit':
        break
     try:
        age = int(age)
        if age < 3:
            print("The movie ticket is FREE for you.")
        elif 3 <= age < 12:
            print("The movie ticket is $10 for you.")
        elif age >= 12:
            print("The movie ticker is $15 for you.")
     except:
        print 'Invalid Age entered !!!'
        pass
```